# Why does Adobe recommend not setting CSP headers for its web fonts?

Tags: content-security-policy

In [this help site](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/fonts/using/content-security-policy.html), Adobe recommends not setting CSP for web fonts saying:

> The CSP policy does not allow you to set an exception for inline styles added by a script from a specific domain.

and

> Adobe Fonts uses inline styles and fonts as data URIs to provide our service, and making exceptions for these negates a lot of the protection provided by a CSP.

What do they mean by it? And if my site already has CSP set, how do I use Adobe fonts if I shouldn't set CSP for it?

Comment: Because it wouldn't be beneficial to them to directly recommend to avoid using their web fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling CSP altogether is not recommended, but you do have a security impact by allowing inline styles. For example, you could use the following policy:

```
default-src 'self';
script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-rAnd0m123' 'unsafe-inline' http: https: 'report-sample';
style-src 'self' 'nonce-rAnd0m123';
object-src 'none';
base-uri 'none';
report-uri https://csp.example.com;
```

This would use [`'strict-dynamic'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#strict-dynamic) for scripts, and would require you to add a nonce to every tag where Adobe Fonts wants to inject their webfonts. This may or may not be possible, depending on how Adobe Fonts works.

## What is the worst that could happen?

If you really have to allow `'unsafe-inline'` in your `style-src` directive, then you may open yourself up to [CSS Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_CSS_Injection_(OTG-CLIENT-005)), which may lead to stolen credentials. Of course, CSP should not your only defense against such things, so please don't see it as such.

## What about the CSP directive on their website?

Adobe suggests the following CSP directive:

```
script-src 'self' use.typekit.net;
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' use.typekit.net;
img-src 'self' p.typekit.net;
connect-src performance.typekit.net
```

The focus on whitelists suggests that this directive was added back when CSP was still very young and only whitelist-based approaches were possible. By using the `'nonce-'` approach, you cam ensure that only the inline scripts loaded in specific locations are allowed.

Comment: Thanks @MechMK1. It's actually surprising that a company as seasoned as Adobe would do this. I'll look up strict-dynamic. I hope browser support for CSP 3 is wide.

Comment: [`strict-dynamic`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#strict-dynamic) is only a valid CSP source for the `script-src` directive. Adobe requires `unsafe-inline` for the `style-src` directive.

Comment: @thirdender I will update the answer accordingly.